# R data cube define hierarchy

Tags: r, data.table, olap-cube, data.cube

I have some problems with the OLapCube package, data.cube:

```
install.packages("data.cube", repos = paste0("https://", c(
    "jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.cube",
    "cloud.r-project.org"
)))
```

Some test data:

```
 library(data.table)
 set.seed(42)

 dt <- CJ(color = c("green","yellow","red"),
            year = 2011:2015,
            month = 1:12,
            status = c("active","inactive","archived","removed")
 )[sample(600)]

 dt[, "value" := sample(4:7/2, nrow(dt), TRUE)]
```

Now I would like to create a cube and apply a hierarchy on the time dimensions. Something like this:

```
library(data.cube)
dc <- as.data.cube(dt, id.vars = c("color", "year", "month", "status"), 
                   measure.vars = "value", 
                   hierarchies = list(time <- list("year, month")))
```

If I run this code i get the error:

```
Error in as.data.cube.data.table(dt, id.vars = c("color", "year", "month",  : 
  identical(names(hierarchies), id.vars) | identical(names(hierarchies),  .... is not TRUE
```

If i try something like

```
hierarchies = list(time <- list("year, month"), color <- list("color"), 
                  status <- list("status"))
```

i get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very well written question.
I see you made example based on `?as.data.cube` examples so I will try to answer your question using that examples too

```
# Original example goes as follows
library(data.cube)
library(data.table)
set.seed(1L)
dt = CJ(color = c("green","yellow","red"),
        year = 2011:2015,
        status = c("active","inactive","archived","removed"))[sample(30)]
dt[, "value" := sample(4:7/2, nrow(dt), TRUE)]

dc = as.data.cube(
  x = dt, id.vars = c("color","year","status"),
  measure.vars = "value",
  hierarchies = sapply(c("color","year","status"),
                       function(x) list(setNames(list(character()), x)),
                       simplify=FALSE)
)
str(dc)
```

Your error seems to be raised when checking validity of hierarchies.
Unfortunately it is not very meaningful error, I created issue [#18](https://gitlab.com/jangorecki/data.cube/issues/18) so this will get improved one day.
So lets compare hierarchies from manual and those created in your example.

```
sapply(c("color","year","status"),
       function(x) list(setNames(list(character()), x)),
       simplify=FALSE) -> h
str(h)
#List of 3
# $ color :List of 1
#  ..$ :List of 1
#  .. ..$ color: chr(0) 
# $ year  :List of 1
#  ..$ :List of 1
#  .. ..$ year: chr(0) 
# $ status:List of 1
#  ..$ :List of 1
#  .. ..$ status: chr(0)     

hierarchies = list(time <- list("year, month"), color <- list("color"), 
                   status <- list("status"))
str(hierarchies)
#List of 3
# $ :List of 1
#  ..$ : chr "year, month"
# $ :List of 1
#  ..$ : chr "color"
# $ :List of 1
#  ..$ : chr "status"
```

We can see that hierarchies in manual is a list of named elements, and your example is a list of unnamed elements.
I believed you misused `<-` where `=` should be used. `<-` are not always equal to `=` operator. You can read more about exactly such case in [3.1.3.1 Assignment `<-` vs `=`](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/r-courses/deepdive.html#language3).

So lets see if fixing that is sufficient

```
hierarchies = list(time = list(c("year, month")), color = list("color"), 
                   status = list("status"))

dc <- as.data.cube(dt, id.vars = c("color", "year", "month", "status"), 
                   measure.vars = "value", 
                   hierarchies = hierarchies)
```

We still have the same error, so names while were required, where not the root cause of the issue. After taking closer look I see now you want to build *time* dimension not having primary key for it.
Important note that you cannot pass multiple column names as single string thus

```
"year, month"
```

should be written as

```
c("year","month")
```

Still we need *time* dimension primary key to be single field, to which *year* and *month* will be just attributes.
So lets make primary key for *time* dimension then, as our time dimension has year-month granularity we will create key on that granularity.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)

dt <- CJ(color = c("green","yellow","red"),
         year = 2011:2015,
         month = 1:12,
         status = c("active","inactive","archived","removed")
)[sample(600)
  ][, yearmonth:=sprintf("%04d%02d", year, month) # this ensure four numbers for year and 2 numbers for month
    ]

dt[, "value" := sample(4:7/2, nrow(dt), TRUE)]
```

Now lets do hierarchies, note that `year` has been changed to `yearmonth`.
In below hierarchies a vector of values `c("year","month")` means that those attributes are dependent on `yearmonth`. Please see more examples in `?as.data.cube` for more complex cases of hierarchies.

```
hierarchies = list(
  color = list(color = list(color = character())),
  yearmonth = list(yearmonth = list(yearmonth = c("year","month"))),
  status = list(status = list(status = character()))
)

dc = as.data.cube(
  x = dt, id.vars = c("color","yearmonth","status"),
  measure.vars = "value",
  hierarchies = hierarchies
)
str(dc)
```

Our `data.cube` has been successfully created. Lets try to query it using key of `yearmonth`

```
dc[, .(yearmonth=201105L)] -> d
as.data.table(d)
dc[, .(yearmonth=201105L), drop=FALSE] -> d
as.data.table(d)
```

Now try to query it using attributes of dimension, a year, and a month, and both

```
dc[, .(year=2011L)] -> d
as.data.table(d) # note that dimension is not being dropped because it still have more than 1 value
dc[, .(month=5L)] -> d
as.data.table(d)
dc[, .(year=2011L, month=5L)] -> d
as.data.table(d) # here dimension has been dropped because there was only single element in that dimension, you can of course use `drop=FALSE` if needed.
```

Hope that helps, good luck!